# Is the Planck mass the minimum required to form a black hole?

Tags: black-holes, mass, physical-constants, elementary-particles

I have heard this stated before, even that this is reason elementary particles do not collapse into a black holes no matter how much they are compressed and why we don't need to worry about them being created inadvertently by a particle-accelerator destroying this planet.  Has this actually been proved?  If so how?

Comment: Elementary particles are point-like. They have no physical extent and can not be "compressed."

Comment: All the nuclear weapons needed to very thoroughly destroy the planet are already in existence. No need to drag particle accelerators into the picture. Particle accelerators have about as good a chance at destroying the planet as my cat.

Comment: Some excessively smart members on this fantastic website downvote good questions, only because the answer is “no”. If you ask, “is electron heavier than proton?” you’d be downvoted just for asking. And yet, if you ask the same in reverse, “is proton heavier than electron?” you’d be upvoted by this crowd, simply because the answer is “yes”. +1

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/442062/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/650571/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 5):

There's a pop-science myth going around that Planck units are somehow known to be fundamental to physics. Like many myths, it's based on a kernel of truth: there are reasons to suspect that at the scale where things tend to be measured in Planck units, some new physics must appear (in particular that quantum gravitational effects will become significant). But no experiment has ever actually shown this, and there is no actual evidence that there's anything special about the Planck length, Planck time, or Planck mass. So far as we know, they're just units like meters, seconds, or kilograms -- the only advantage they have (so far as we know now) is that they can be defined without reference to arbitrary human scale constants.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. Planck units typically represent bounds of physical meaning in modern physics. The answer incorrectly suggests the “possibility” instead of “necessity” of new physics beyond the Planck level and likely much sooner.

Comment: The Planck *scale* is where our *theories* are known to be incomplete. This doesn't mean that Planck units themselves are special somehow, other than being convenient for measuring things at that scale. Moreover, while new *theories* are necessary, that doesn't mean that new *physics* , i.e. new behavior or effects, are necessary, although it seems likely they will be. The only honest answer to "what happens at the Planck scale?" is "we don't know". And as you yourself say, the new theories/physics may come in well above the Planck scale.

Answer (score 2):

What matters for creating a black hole is the density not the mass. This discussed in [What is exactly the density of a black hole and how can it be calculated?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/26515/what-is-exactly-the-density-of-a-black-hole-and-how-can-it-be-calculated/218816) though the equation for the density required is not especially informative:

$$ \rho = \frac{3c^6}{32 \pi G^3 M^2} \tag{1} $$

So to make some mass a black hole, and this applies whether or not it's a fundamental particle, we need to compress it until its density reaches this value.

For a fundamental particle we "compress" by localising it. Quantum objects are always delocalised over some region of space and their density is determined by how delocalised they are. In principle we can localise a particle to increase its density, but there is a wrinkle with this.

When we localise a particle we always increase its energy. The reason for this is a little involved, but a handwaving explanation is that the uncertainty principle requires:

$$ \Delta x \Delta p \ge \frac\hbar2 $$

Localising the particle means decreasing $\Delta x$ so $\Delta p$ has to increase, and that increases the energy. But Einstein's famous equation tells us that $E = mc^2$ so as we localise the particle and increase its energy we are increasing its mass and therefore increasing its density. That means at some point the density will increase above the critical value given in equation (1), and at that point the particle will form a black hole.

Note that it doesn't matter what particle we start with. Even for a neutrino the act of localising it would increase the mass and density.

Anyhow, we can calculate what size the collapse happens at, and it turns out to be about a Planck length, and the mass at which it happens is about the Planck mass. I say "about" because we would need a theory of quantum gravity to be sure what happens and no such theory exists at the moment.

Finally, you ask about experimental tests but the energies involved in this process are vastly greater than anything we can achieve in colliders. Unless some unexpected rears its head, e.g. [large extra dimensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_extra_dimensions), we are not going to be experimentally testing this for the foreseeable future.

Comment: This is a great answer!  Question:  Why does localizing necessarily increase energy?  Could it not just increase uncertainty about it's direction vector?

Comment: @DerekSeabrooke "localising" a particle basically means confining it into a box of some size Δx where reducing Δx makes the particle more and more localised. But a particle in a box has a zero point energy that increases as we decrease the box size. It is the increase in this zero point energy that increases the mass in accordance with E = mc².

Comment: would this not violate conservation of energy?

Comment: @DerekSeabrooke No, because the extra energy comes from the work done by whatever is exerting a pressure on the particle to localise it. Just like when you compress a gas the increased internal energy comes from the work done to compress it.

Comment: So the take home message is yes, the Planck mass is the minimum to form a blackhole?

Comment: @DerekSeabrooke Yes